# confusion of a c++ pointer segmentation

Tags: c++

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(){

  int x = 5;
  int y[4] = {0,9,3,1};
  int *add_x = &y[2];


  cout << y[1] << endl;      /*1st output*/

  cout << sizeof(x) << endl;  /* 2nd output*/
  cout << add_x << endl;       /* 0x7fff20d9b1d8*/  /*3rd output*/

  cout << &add_x << endl;      /* 0x7fff20d9b1c8*/  /*4th output*/
  cout << &add_x[0] << endl;   /* 0x7fff20d9b1d8*/  /*5th output*/
  cout << &add_x[1] << endl;   /* 0x7fff20d9b1dc*/
  cout << &add_x[2] << endl;

  cout << &y[2] << endl;       /* 0x7fff20d9b1d8 */


}
```

Hi all, I am just wondering what is the difference between the 3rd, 4th, and the 5th output in the code here?

I know the 3rd output is the address of `y[2]` (because this is how I define `*add_x` which is a pointer to `y[2]`), but how about `&add_x` ( I know this is the address of `add_x` which is a pointer).

what is the `&add_x[0]`, `&add_x[1]`, `&add_x[2]` here?

because `&add_x` is an address of a pointer I think, so how come when I put in the [0],[1], [2] after `&add_x`, it gives me something that seem to be an address. So what exactly is `&add_x[0]`, `&add_x[1]`?

and what exactly is the difference between `add_x` and `&add_x[0]` (i.e. the 3rd and 5th output), are they supposed to be the same? because the output of "cout" are the same.

Comment: @ohn_w What is the 5th output?

Comment: You seem to be awfully close to understanding this; what are you stuck on? Did you read too quickly and think the fourth output is the same as the third and fifth? (Look at the second-to-last hex digit.) How is it you understand that `&y[2]` is parsed as `&(y[2])` (address taken last), but then read `&add_x[0]` as putting `[0]` on `&add_x` (which would be the incorrect `(&add_x)[0]`) instead of matching the `y` case (the correct `&(add_x[0])`)?